# how to show field value when i store its id from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, `holiday_package` and `main_attractions`.

`holiday_package` contains the field package_title and `main_attractions` contains package_title and main_attraction fields. I am inserting package_title id from holiday_package table to main_attractions table field package_title.

I want to show package_title and main_attraction data from main_attractions table to administrator in admin panel, so instead of package_title id I want to show its value. How can I write a SQL query for that? Please help me!

My php code:

```
$sql = "select * from main_attractions";
      $i = 1;

    $res = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 

    if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {

    echo "<tr>
      <td>".$i++."</td>
      <td>".$row["package_title"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["main_attraction"]."</td>
      <td><a href='edit-main-attraction-details.php?id=$row[id]'>Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href='delete-main-attraction.php?id=$row[id]' onclick='return confirmSubmit();'>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>";
     }
    }
```

Comment: Use join between two tables main_attractions and holiday_package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With join you can do it
 like this

holiday_package

```
 package_title  package_id
_____________  _____________
    A                  1
    B                  2
    c                  3
```

main_attractions

```
 main_attraction    package_title
_____________     _____________
    A1                    1
    B1                    2
    c1                    3
```

So

```
select holiday_package.package_title,main_attraction from main_attractions 
left join holiday_package on main_attractions.package_title=holiday_package.package_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from main_attractions left join holiday_package on main_attractions.package_title = holiday_package.package_id
```

In place of * you can mention the names of fields to fetch

Comment: This is excatly what @ashkufaraz answered.

Comment: I was submitting my answer, my internet got disconnected. So it got published late. Sorry I didnt checked the earlier post.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. It is very help full to me